# Saving a Html.DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

How can I save into my db this the selected option, Right now It's saving all the data but the ProfileText that is what I need...
I think I need to add an asp-for but I dont know where to be honest, or if it's a different way please tell me.
Here is my view:

```
@model HCCBPOHR.Data.Candidate
@*@model HCCBPOHR.DomainModel.CandidateModel*@
 @*@model HCCBPOHR.Services.CandidateService.PostBoth*@
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "CandidateCreate";
}
<h2>CandidateCreate</h2>
<h4>Candidate</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-action="CandidateCreate">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Number" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Number" class="form-control" maxlength="9" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Number" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.DropDownList("ProfileText", "Select Profile")
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="CV" type="file" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="CV" type="file" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" onclick="this.disabled=true;this.form.submit();" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

Here is my Model:

```
public class Candidate : BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string ProfileText { get; set; }
    public Byte[] CV { get; set; }
    public string CVNAME { get; set; }
    public List<Profile> ProfileList { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I'm sending the List to the View:

```
public IActionResult CandidateCreate(int postId)
    {

        using (var applicationcontext = new ApplicationContext())
        {
            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = applicationcontext.Profile.Select(c => new SelectListItem{Value = c.ProfileText,Text = c.ProfileText});
            ViewBag.ProfileText = items.ToList();
            return View();
        }
    }
```

The error that I'm having right now is

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view change the code to:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <select asp-for="ProfileText" asp-items="@Model.ProfileList"></select>
</div>
```

Then in your model you'll have a property which we can call `ProfileText` which will then get post to the server when the form is submitted.

Change your model by introducing a new prop as follows:

```
public SelectList ProfileList { get; set; }
```

Now in your action your will need to do:

```
var model = new Candidate();
...
model.ProfileList = new SelectList(YourProfileListFromDbOrSomeWhereElse);
return View(model);
```

Please note you can also use `SelectList(IEnumerable, string dataValueField, string dataTextField)`Constructor if you want to set the `dataValueField` and `dataTextField`. I do not know how you get your `ProfileList` and what it contains so hence why I've only made use of the `SelectList(IEnumerable items);` Constructor.

Further reading **[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.selectlist?view=aspnetcore-2.1)**

Comment: I'm getting this error: Cannot implictly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Kust<HCCBPOHR.Data.Profile>'toSystem.cOLLECTIONS.gEERIC.iNUMERABLE<mICORSOFR.ASPNETCORE.MVC.RENDERINC.SELECTLISTITEM"

Comment: sure I will add it to the question

Comment: @DorinMunteanu and your action code please where you populate your `public List<Profile> ProfileList`

Comment: @DorinMunteanu updated my answer, let me know how you get on

Comment: I'm getting an error on `SelectList` in my Model.
This Line `public SelectList ProfileList { get; set; }`

Comment: The type or namespace name SelectList could not be foun are you missing a using directive or an assemblu reference ?

Comment: Download `microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc` from Nuget Package Manager that will get rid of the error. You're just missing the assembly that's all. Once downloaded, do `using AspNetCore.Mvc`

Comment: Now my program doesnt work because i was using asp.net-core and with this aspnetcore mvc everything is getting an error...

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, you are not populating the dropdownlist. I think it's better practice to have the values that can be selected(in a SelectList or string list) and a variable that will hold the selected value in your model and use DropDownListFor. the syntax would be:

*@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProfileText, new SelectList(Model.ProfileList,  "name"), new {(here html attributes)@class = "form-control"})*

After doing that you will get the selected value when posting the model

Comment: I'm getting an error : `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Comment: your view is expecting to recieve a model but your are returning the view without passing any model.
(in last line you have return View({pass your model here})).
and pass within your model the list. NOT in Viewbag.